# Data logging over 5km range

Tags: measurement, datalogger

I am working on a project of designing a system for leak detection in pipelines. I want to monitor pressure/flow in both endings of a 5km long pipe and acoustic emissions onto some crucial points of the pipe.

For that reason I am intending to prototype some data-loggers. These will be consist from a ADC, a micro-controller and a SD card.

The real problem now, is the synchronous monitoring of many signals along 5km range. I want to trigger the data-loggers exactly at the same time, in order to keep synchronized different measurements from different locations.

My question is: what is the most appropriate method to achieve this?

1. use a cellphone and two GSM modules to trigger the data-loggers at the same time?
2. use some LoRa modules to transmit the measured data into a PC/laptop?
   (obviously the SD card is no needed any more).
3. use two cellphones to transmit data via internet?
4. anything else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would say the cellular network is the most most developed infrastructure for this. But you should think of a reliable protocol if you need an exact timing.

Comment: RDS is doable especially if you want low power.

Comment: "synchronous monitoring", "exactly at the same time": can you give us an ordner of magnitude for what you consider "exact"? Is it ok if these sensors are triggered a millisecond apart, or what kind of synchronizity do you need?

Comment: also, "oil pipeline", to me, doesn't sound like you can rely on any GSM coverage.

Comment: *how often* will you trigger measurements? *how much* data will you end up with? Add some more background on what you need to do.

Comment: "I want to trigger the data-loggers exactly at the same time". Same time can mean a lot of different things. +/-1 sec?  +/- 1ms? +/-1 us? +/- 1ns?

Comment: @jojosthegreat : If you do not react to these question in the very near future, people will vote to close this question as unclear, and rightfully so – in it's current form, it's underdefined.

Comment: Thank you Markus. You are right. These pipes are full of fresh fuel

Comment: The sampling rate will be 1MS/s maximum. An error of +/- 1 sample (and more) does not bothering me. In the end, all I want is to plot many signals in the same time axis.

Comment: If you don't need the data in realtime, you can just timestamp it. No need for online synchronization.

Comment: How much data does that account to? Like, for how long do you intend to measure? I'd expect 1MS/s of let's say 8 bit samples not to be continuously streamable via LTE, and it's definitely impossible through GSM (which effectively won't do more than 48kb/s on upstream...)

Comment: @EugeneSh. timestamping with 1µs accuracy is everything but easy.

Comment: Thank you Andy. An RDS system is a cheap and nice solution. I didn't knew that it can send data with ~1kbps

Comment: @jojosthegreat 1MS/s is very much for everything but very beefy microcontrollers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You don't need to mark every point, right? Just the first one. But yes, you need the local clocks to have a very precise known difference.

Comment: @EugeneSh. not 100% true; no two oscillators are identical, and you usually have to synchronize continously if you don't want ADC clocks to drift apart. That's why there's timing synchronizers in every high-rate wireless standard.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like an over-specification.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and even so, getting things down to a 1µs accuracy isn't easy at all remotely. Do you have a suggestion how to do that?

Comment: @jojosthegreat you should really add those requirements to your question, by the way.

Comment: @jojosthegreat how does 1kb/s help you at all if you need to sample with 1MS/s?

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for your replies. But how can I timestamp a signal with 1MS/s? As far as I know, real time clocks use 32kHz signals.

Comment: @jojosthegreat this has nothing to do with real time clocks. It's much harder than getting a simple real time clock. The typical real time clock has an oscillator that's maybe 25ppm accurate, meaning that over the course of a single hour, that clock would be off by 90000 samples. Your +/-1 Sample @ 1MS/s requirement is *really* hard and *nearly* impossible if you're not an experienced wireless device designer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller GPS can be used for clock synchronization AFAIK. Not sure it is applicable here though..

Comment: @EugeneSh. that would be the easiest solution I could think of, yes. But GPSDOs that offer a clock output start in the multi-100USD range.

Comment: @jojosthegreat are you *sure* you need 1MS/s for every sensor? What kind of signal are you considering? Are you sure you need 1µs alignment?

Comment: No, I wrote 1MS/s maximum. I haven't seen these signals plotted, so I assumed that a sampling rate of 1Ms, covers any case.

Comment: Yes, but to buy a loaf of bread, I'd need a maximum of 1 Million Dollars, too. **Engineering is about knowing what your application realistically demands**, not setting an arbitrarily high demand. What is the maximum bandwidth of the signal you're observing? I mean, pressure and acoustics definitely will never change at 0.5MHz -- that sounds mechanically impossible, and also, the 1MHz wide microphone has yet to be introduced to me. So: put down realistic requirements first. Otherwise, you'll just get useless answers and waste everyone's time.

Comment: @jojosthegreat Specifying a *maximum* sampling rate without minimum is pretty useless. You should have exact specifications.

Comment: Thank you one more time for your answers. I will try to find out some specs. But don't get angry with me. I have never seen them plotted

Comment: it's not about plotting. It's about understanding your application at a very basic level. You're supposed to build a sensor network, yet you can't even tell us the bandwidth of your signals – hence, you're keeping the info necessary to give you any meaningful answer to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be bad receiption for GSM cell phones at some points of a long pipeline. I would suggest using GPS receivers for exact timing. GPS allows sub microseconds precision of synchronization. In remote areas with no cell phone receiption there will be still GPS receiption, you only need a non obstructed view to the sky.

Comment: There are plenty of integrated GSM+GPS ICs and products available for sending the location of your lost dog/what have you. Just make sure you can get time stamp from the GPS part since it may not be available as a parameter on all circuits.

Answer (score -1):

The most accurate way I can think of synchronizing sensor reads is to synchronize the microcontrollers with a GPRS module using AT commands. You can use AT commands to get the current network time. The specific AT command for that is

```
AT+CCLK?
```

[GPRS AT Commands - See Page 69.](https://www.multitech.com/manuals/s000463f.pdf) You may want to store the value received from that and the current internal time since startup of your microcontroller, and use an offset from that to determine a more precise time. Now that you would have your controllers' times synchronized to a possibly accurate value, you could set them to log at very specific times, or just short intervals. You should be able to do this as you wanted with an SD card, since no outside means of triggering a sensor read would be required now.

---

EDIT: This was my original solution, but as Marcus Mueller pointed out, it would be highly inaccurate. Don't use it.

The way that I would go about approaching this is to have all sensors/microcontrollers synced with an internet time server. Then, simply set up each controller to log values at precise times. This should be able to be done easily as long as you have ways of connecting your microcontrollers to the internet. I'm not sure of your environment, but as an example, this article about [Connecting an Arduino to an Internet Time Server](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Internet-Time-Client/?ALLSTEPS) may possibly be of use to you. However, that example will only work with Ethernet or WiFi connectivity. If you're not in an obscure place, that would be fine.

Comment: OP demands +/- 1S accuracy with at a sampling rate of 1MS/s. That means +/- 1µs. That accuracy is *physically* impossible with high layer network protocols such as NTP. Especially over high & high variance latency data channels such as GPRS. Really, NTP over GPRS is a **really** bad idea. You will be off by >> 0.1s!!!

Comment: Why did this get marked as solution? It solves none of the problems of your question.

Comment: This method would be accurate to +/- one sample because of the constant time syncs. If, say, you update the time every second, one microcontroller isn't going to immediately desyncronize by 500ms. Even if they aren't syncronized to the precise internet time, they will be syncronized to eachother due to them (hopefully) using the same technologies.

Comment: No it won't. How should there be any constant time sync? The variance is far too high for any control loop to compensate this to the level OP demands.

Comment: Also, general purpose operating systems like Linux will have a hard time doing something with 1µs accuracy at all – you will still need to program special hardware to trigger ADC recording at any specific time. That's the hard part, not setting up something that connects to the internet and polls an NTP server.

Comment: Perhaps using GPRS would be better, you're right on that. This is all I have as a response to the originally asked question. OP should edit their question to reflect their current desires.

Comment: You're not reading closely, no matter what you do, a somehow configured Linux computer that gets time from somewhere else through a network protocol can mathematically not suffice to estimate the current time with enough precision – that's the Cramer-Rao bound for estimators, basically.

Comment: I mean, think about it. The time the first bit takes to travel from the modem to the computer, through the serial/USB/network/PCIe/whatever stack, up to the driver, then to userland will be a) much much much longer than 1µs and b) vary by much much more than 1µs.

Comment: So basically, OP is screwed no matter what he does?

Comment: no. He just can't use something like a raspberry pi running a normal operating system and hope to get 1µs of accuracy. But that's not OP's only choice! However, synchronizing something to that amount is pretty hard, and it took about 40 years of synchronizer research until mobile phones were able to synchronize their **internal** circuitry that well to a base station – which doesn't mean it's possible to use that clock for anything else. You really have to have quite some idea on signal processing to build a set of devices that are so well phase-aligned.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments under OP's question, there's devices (GPS disciplined oscillators) that are able to give you a very sharp edge at exact times, and also supply you with a very accurate (better than 100ppb, which you would need to stay within 1µs sync over a couple of days) oscillator clock, that you could use to derive the ADC clock. But these are very intelligent, complex devices and cost hundreds of dollars.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry for putting down a useless answer and wasting everyone's time, anyway.

Comment: I want to second that – your answer is worth a lot to others reading this later!